# Virtual Box Max OS Sierra Start Error

Tags: macos, virtualbox

when i try to start my virutal machine i get an error
i followed this article
https://i2.wp.com/www.Wikigain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Installing-macOS-Sierra-on-VirtualBox.jpg

Here is the error fie virtualbox hardening log

http://www.filedropper.com/vboxhardening

its a big file so cant paste here

Comment: SuperUser might be more helpful here.  Also what OS are you running?  It looks like Windows

Comment: If so what you are doing is illegal.

Comment: yes its windows . just wanted to transfer whastapp from android to iphone using this watoi tool on github. recently bought an iphone

Comment: Also I can't access filedropper.  I **strongly** advise you don't go ahead with this but it's your choice and it's still pretty cool (if not risky).

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by uninstalling virtual box and installing again (updated version). Probably some configurations have been corrupted. But its working now